# Posts reaching 1000 downvotes don't get rounded down to 'k' on mobile version of site

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, rounding

On mobile web (Chrome 75.0 for Android), a post reaching a score of -1,097 sees its score overlapping the vote arrow:

[image: bug on mobile web]

This should probably read -1.1k, like the post above (positively upvoted).

Comment: It is obvious they didn't design for this ....

Comment: There's a lot of bugs as well on on the mobile-web as in the mobile-app. I don't think they maintain or develop it anymore. There hasn't been updates for ages.

Comment: What’s the point of the arrow anyway? I don’t have it, [and the score therefore displays correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw0MH.jpg).

Comment: They will fix that. But when they reach -10,000, it will break again.

Comment: Just wait til it gets -2147483649 votes. That's when things start to get real interesting.

Comment: Negative 1k is an exceptionally abnormal case. I suggest to keep it as is. Positive 1k is normal.

Comment: @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ just because it's uncommon doesn't mean they should let a display bug remain.

Comment: @Lundin using floats at that point might help, and if it ever hits the float limit it is either extremely far into the future (and by then there is probably a better solution) or SE has a really massive bot problem

Comment: @Yay Yeah lets use floating points for votes +1.0000001   :)

Comment: @Lundin or +1.0

Comment: -1.2k would still be rather close to overlapping

Comment: Maybe because the devs didn't thinking that someone would get at least 1000 downvotes.

Comment: Marking this as declined since this is no longer the mobile UI we have for our sites