# Questions with a score of -1000 and lower are not rounded in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, score, rounding

Questions with a score of 1000 or higher are rounded, e.g. 1380 becomes 1.4k. This doesn't happen for questions with score of -1000 or lower, resulting in a very small text (it's readable in the screenshot below, but mostly because mobile screens tend to have a high screen density and their screenshots blow up when uploaded). I'd expect the score to be shown as -1.5k.

**This is not a duplicate of [Posts reaching 1000 downvotes don't get truncated to kilos on mobile web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334504/posts-reaching-1000-downvotes-dont-get-truncated-to-kilos-on-mobile-web) as this question is about the iOS app, while that question is about the mobile website.** The two things use different methods to render the scores: the score for the mobile website gets rendered server-side (IIRC a combination of C# and HTML), while the app gets its data from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) and performs the rounding client-side in native iOS code.

[image]

<sub>I do know app development is [currently frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232) and that the Stack Exchange employees have more pressing matters at hand.</sub>

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334504/398063)

Comment: @Suvitruf no, that's a different codebase (HTML / C# vs. Swift)

Comment: @Glorfindel only if they round numbers on the client side)

Comment: @Suvitruf the app uses the API and it doesn't round. The website rounds server-side.

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, boi D:

Comment: Note: this is the case also for the native android app.

Comment: [We thought](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/78429) this is an API Bug Report, thus remains open; Glo - Mobile and API Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341892/stack-exchange-mobile-apps-still-use-on-hold-for-recently-closed-questions

Comment: @Rob there's no way to fix this in the API alone. `score` is an integer, not a string: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post