# Why do I get so many downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-answer

I am new and getting lots of downvotes. Can you see what I did wrong in these two examples? Help would be very much appreciated.

1. [Show your work: one simple trick to make meta effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366288/135565)

[image]

2. [Posts reaching 1000 downvotes don't get rounded down to 'k' on mobile version of site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334504/posts-reaching-1000-downvotes-dont-get-rounded-down-to-k-on-mobile-version-of/366286#366286)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: Edits which invalidate existing posts should not be made, this is clearly stated in the [help], please don't try to circumvent best practice.

Comment: Please don't remove the question from your post.  If you have another question, please ask it via the [Ask Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Otherwise, don't make edits that are off-topic for this post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your [first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366288/622284), you said:

> you have to explain deep or else they don't know what you want

Well... Yeah, that's what the question was, in a nutshell, saying. Answers are meant to answer the question, or in the case of Meta, at least further discussion on the subject at hand. This answer does neither.

On your [second answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366286/622284)'s first revision, you posted:

> that is probably because the mobile web is different from the computer web, try again on a computer and refreshing the mobile web

Yep, the post author knew this. This was a bug report asking for the problem described to be fixed in the mobile web version of the site.

You then edited that second answer to say:

> try to load it on a computer:)

Yes, the author knows that rendering the content on the desktop version will display it correctly, and is hoping that a developer would fix the described problem for the mobile view. This is just commentary. I recognize that this is a bug report and not really a "question," but this answer doesn't help anyone and isn't needed whatsoever.

Remember that the answer box is for *answers* to questions. From the [help center on deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers):

> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed.

Downvoting lets users with access to the [ability to vote to delete answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) help delete answers that should be deleted, hence the downvotes on your answers.

Comment: TLDR: quite frankly the answers were *terrible*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53617/12102 not sure what's happening here though

Comment: @uhoh that's "trivial answer", a short answer mentioning a link to another post on the same site will automatically be converted to comment.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. oic [Automatic comments can also be generated on behalf of users who don't have enough reputation to comment; these users cannot edit or delete those comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757) but in this case there's no link and probably the user is just trying to game the system and/or abuse the feature. *Thanks!* (nice mask btw!)

Comment: @uhoh ah, I was referring to [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/how-are-voyagers-16-thrusters-oriented/53617#comment174783_32223) instead. The now-deleted answer wasn't a trivial answer and just a standard NAA.

Comment: Oh I see the continuity now, it was a sort-of good-faith attempt to reply to my comment using the answer post. Got it.